# MySQL Query Not Ordering Results as Expected

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a database with three tables (cl, s, and cl_s) and perform a query to select data from these tables. However, the results are not being ordered as I expected. Here's the SQL code I'm using:

```
CREATE TABLE cl (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name ENUM('a', 'b')
);

INSERT INTO cl (name) VALUES
('a'),
('b'),
('b'),
('a'),
('b'),
('b');

CREATE TABLE s (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name ENUM('a', 'b'),
  s_name VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO s (name, s_name) VALUES
('a', 'a1'),
('a', 'a2'),
('b', 'b1'),
('b', 'b2'),
('b', 'b3');

CREATE TABLE cl_s (
  cl_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  s_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (cl_id) REFERENCES cl(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES s(id)
);

INSERT INTO cl_s (cl_id, s_id) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 3),
(2, 4),
(2, 5),
(3, 3),
(3, 4),
(4, 1),
(4, 2),
(5, 3),
(5, 4),
(5, 5);
```

for

```
SELECT 
  cl.id,
  cl.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(s.s_name ORDER BY s.s_name) AS s_names,
  COUNT(*) OVER() as total_rows
FROM cl
LEFT JOIN cl_s ON cl.id = cl_s.cl_id
LEFT JOIN s ON cl_s.s_id = s.id
GROUP BY cl.id
ORDER BY cl.name DESC
```

I expect the results to be ordered by the name column in descending order, but the actual results are not ordered correctly. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it?

I tried several modifications to the query to identify the issue:

Removing GROUP_CONCAT: When I removed the
`GROUP_CONCAT(s.s_name ORDER BY s.s_name) AS s_names line,`
the results were ordered correctly.

Removing COUNT(*) OVER(): I also tried removing the
`COUNT(*) OVER() as 1total_rows` 
line, and the results were again ordered correctly.

Changing the ORDER BY Clause: When I changed the `ORDER BY` clause to `order by max(cl.name)`, the results were sorted correctly.

but i want thet it work without this changes

Comment: Don't you need to add `cl.name` to the `GROUP BY`, since it's not being aggregated?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: my version  is 8.0.34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add total_rows to the order by clause, as that is separating the rows into partitions:

ORDER BY total_rows, cl.Name DESC

Comment: thanks it works,
Can u give me more details on how it solves this,
and way it happened?

Comment: The over() clause was causing the data to partition, hence breaking the data into smaller partitions. This was impeding the order by to work properly.